# Possible to have multiple FilterAttributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, filterattribute

Is it possible to stack multiple filter attributes? For instance I have this attribute which checks if a person has permission to "Administrator" OR "Queue"

```
    [ClientPortalSecured("Administrator", "Queue")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(this.GetModel());
    }
```

but what if I wanted to check for these AND something else? Is it possible to do something like this?

```
    [ClientPortalSecured("Administrator", "Queue")]
    [ClientPortalSecured("abc")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(this.GetModel());
    }
```

I currently get "Duplicate 'ClientPortalSecured' attribute" compiler error when I try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it. Added

`[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = true)]`

to my ClientPortalSecuredAttribute class